# Are there biological reasons why life expectancy is lower for men in most countries of the world?

Tags: human-biology, lifespan

I've been checking life expectancy figures for men versus women in many countries of the world and the figures for men sometimes are terrifying. Countries like Russia have a 12 years gap in disfavor of men. Developed countries have usually a 4-5 years gap in disfavor of men. My country Argentina has a 7 years gap. African countries and middle east countries where supposedly women have a harder life because of religion have usually a 3 years gap in disfavor of men. So far I haven't found a single country where men lives more than women.

Now I know there are more men than women who dies in homicides, suicides, work accidents, wars, etc. men are more likely to get addictions because of depression, etc. but aside of all that, is there any biological reason why men lives less than women everywhere?

Comment: Here is a recent review: http://www.cell.com/cell-metabolism/pdf/S1550-4131(16)30237-6.pdf

Comment: If I recall correctly from my US history class, in colonial America the life expectancy for men exceeded the life expectancy for women, but you are correct about the general trend.

Comment: Three little words... "Hold my beer".

Comment: @omegacron Non true. Women now drink as much alcohol as men, global study finds https://www.theguardian.com/society/2016/oct/24/women-drink-alcohol-men-global-study

Comment: @Pablo You missed Omegacron’s point - it refers to the effect of testosterone (and alcohol) on men’s judgement. See: [The 21 Greatest Moments In "Hold My Beer" History](https://www.buzzfeed.com/daves4/hold-my-beer?utm_term=.gjnEEBdVA#.xaWaaBeoV)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are both biological and  social factor for that:

## Biological

- Females have two X chromosomes. When mutations in genes of the X chromosome occur, females have a second X to compensate. Males, on the other hand gave just one chromosome X and all genes its genes express themselves, even those lethal or deleterious.
- Females have better resistance to biological aging and hormones and the role of women in reproduction are known to be associated to greater longevity (e.g. estrogen offers some protection against heart disease because it facilitates elimination of bad cholesterol while testosterone has been linked to violence and risk taking).
- The female body evolved to accommodate the needs of pregnancy and breast feeding hence deals better with making reservation. This ability has been linked to a female's better ability to cope with overeating and eliminating excess food

## Social

This "advantage" women seem to have was once nullified by the status and life conditions they had back then, as the risks and the burden of pregnancy and the lack of attention to health and rights women had in a way more misogynist world.

Given the economic, social and political changes that the world experienced, a general progress in female life conditions took place and women have not only regained their biological advantage, but have gone beyond it, achieving higher life expectation. Social and comportamental factor are involved in this higher longevity:

- Women tend to engage in fewer risky and bad for health behaviors than men do, e.g. men have more problems than women with alcoholism, smoking and road accidents.
- The world is still very sexist and the gender roles to be played would expose men to higher risks. Regarding to work, for instance, although women nowadays participate in the work force, their professional activities remain different and are less prejudicial to their health (on average).
- Also regarding to  very sexist gender roles, men are expected to be strong and manly and powerful and women are expected to be gracious young and beautiful. As a result of that, women are more attentive to their body and health, engage themselves in more healthy activities and benefit more from medicine and science. Men on the other hand submit their bodies to challenges from early ages and tend to neglect their bodies needs.

---

You can have access to detailed statistics (male/female, country by country, life expectancy and other health data) here:

http://www.who.int/gho/publications/world_health_statistics/2016/Annex_B/en/

And also, read more about the issue here:

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-is-life-expectancy-lo/

http://www.who.int/mediacentre/news/releases/2016/health-inequalities-persist/en/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy#cite_note-10

Comment: Good on you for adding the *social* reasons.

Comment: Do you have research to share that supports your claim that "*women have not only regained their biological advantage, but have gone beyond it*"? In general, the answer could benefit from references in the scientific literature on the issue. The only one of your references that is not just stating the existence of the phenomenon, is the one from Sci. Am. that @rotaredom linked before you, and we have no way of evaluating it as there is no scientific literature cited in it. That is especially true for the discussion on the social factors you mention, which does not sound scientific at all.

Comment: Good answer, could you clarify the line "and all genes its genes express themselves"?

Comment: @vkehayas considering social "sciences" dont use the scientific method because many times they dont do experiments but try to assert their theories with observations or interpretations, or they dont use valid methods for validation because they cant isolate what's going on in the mind, because there are no tools for doing so, asking for an answer in regards to social disciplines to be "scientific" is asking for the impossible.

Comment: @Pablo I thoroughly and vehemently disagree that social sciences cannot be scientific *a priori*! I only disagree with the verbiage used in the linked article, and consequently the answer since it is basically echoing the points therein. The issues can be in principle empirically addressed but I found no evidence in the linked article. Also my request for references was for the whole answer, as none were given for any of the claims made.

Comment: I also disagree that social studies are not science and are not done with scientific methods. @vkehayas, life expectancy studies in past years are not easy because this data were not recorded in early ages. But this conclusion comes from interpretation of a few data (e.g. life expec in  royal family of Wales and their related ones, which shows that men in early ages lived longer)... There is also a very well known issue: maternal death. Nowadays, every day, more than 800 women die from pregnancy or childbirth related causes. Can you imagine how it was in early ages?

Comment: Also, there are some studies linking higher female mortality with traditions leading to discriminatory treatment against females... If I'm not mistaken they were gave India as example, but this is a real issue everywhere

Comment: Mortality aside, and selective breeding aside, is there also a reason why there are (naturally) more males are born than females? Is the gestation period changing over time?  Women live longer? These questions reach back to hunter gatherer times when "work accidents" were probably somewhat more serious.

Comment: It's arguable that the greater risk-taking of men is attributable to testosterone and other biological differences, as well.

Comment: Social point, which you kind of mentioned: Women go to the doctor far more frequently. That alone can make up for a lot of the difference.

Comment: Women have two X chromosomes but only one is active in each cell, see Barr body - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barr_body

Comment: I found this article https://visual.ons.gov.uk/how-has-life-expectancy-changed-over-time/ . Life expectancy for women was higher than men 2 centuries ago. Now the gap duplicated.

Comment: Is there a reference for "This "advantage" women seem to have was once nullified by the status and life conditions they had back then, as the risks and the burden of pregnancy and the lack of attention to health and rights women had in a way more misogynist world. Given ... changes that the world experienced, a general progress in female life conditions took place and women have not only regained their biological advantage, but have gone beyond it, achieving higher life expectation." @Pablo lists evidence the gap still favors women in less developed countries today & developed ones in the past

Comment: @Silverfish - as a wholly random single (out of hundreds) examples, look at funding and attention for breast cancer vs prostate cancers.

Comment: @Silverfish - another one is that the much-mentioned in the answers risk-taking isn't only biological (testosterone) but also social (sexual competition between males). This is largely sociological, based on what kinds of mates women choose to both date and procreate with (compare: Mick Jagger vs. Bill Gates).

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of factors playing in here.  You've pointed out the surface reasons that can sometimes contribute: work accidents, style of life, etc.  However, there are biological causes as you suspected.

Probably the most obvious has to do with the difference between their hormones.  Testosterone (male hormone) is associated with violence and risk taking.  This would tend to contribute to men having at least a slightly shorter lifespan.  Estrogen, on the other hand, is associated with the removal of cholesterol from the blood.  This may lower the risk of females dying from heart diseases, raising the average female life span.

Some hypothesize that a large section of the difference simply comes from lifestyle resulting from those hormones, per [American Scientific](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-is-life-expectancy-lo/): Men tend to want to be caricatured as strong and tough (result of testosterone), whereas women tend to be more concerned with maintaining their bodies, keeping themselves beautiful, etc.  Obviously, this is hard to measure in a conclusive way, so scientific articles and measurements are hard to produce.

However, there are also diseases which men are more prone to because they can lose the Y chromosome in their blood (this is suspected to be induced by smoking, [along with other potential causes](http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/41579/title/Vanishing-Y-Chromosomes/)), such as [cancer](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A734248&dswid=1431), and even [some forms of Alzheimer's](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:948797/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

#### Edit:

Another reason hypothesized that women tend to last longer than men is that they are less prone to serious genetic mutations on the sex chromosome, since they have a double X instead of two totally different XY chromosomes (See *Why women live longer than men: Sex differences in longevity* (2006) by Steven N. Austad: Gender Medicine 3(2): pp. 86-88).

Comment: It is noteworthy that sex differences occur for infants as well, so I'm not sure that a behavioural explanation like this explains the phenomenon. Your paragraph starting "A large section of the difference..." should be backed up by research papers, otherwise you may be accused of parroting the stereotype-promoting language used in the Sci.Am. article you linked to. An alternative theory is that [lifespan simply depends on body size](http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/49321/1/bulletin_1992_70%282%29_259-267.pdf)

Comment: @vkehayas you have a very good point.  Unfortunately, I have to run for a biology seminar right now, but I'll try to scratch up some references afterwards.  :)

Comment: Men get a lot more heart attacks. Perhaps 2% mortality per year after 50!!! https://archive.cnx.org/resources/b32e423e49c72ec63021d4c65847d375433a2888/CNX_Psych_14_03_HeartAtt.jpg   .............. 
 https://www.google.fr/search?q=heart+attacks+in+men+vs+women&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT7_S57Y7XAhWQDRoKHdZYBlEQ_AUICigB&biw=1026&bih=606#imgrc=9KXzzK1p17V8tM:

Answer (score 1):

One reason for that delay in onset of cardiovascular disease could be that women are relatively iron-deficient compared to men — especially younger women, those in their late teens and early 20s — because of menstruation. Iron plays a very important part in the reactions in our cells that produce free radicals, which damage cell membranes and DNA, and may translate into aging the cell. Postmenopausal women lose this benefit https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2821138/

Here is a well researched article on why women live longer than men https://ourworldindata.org/why-do-women-live-longer-than-men

Answer (score 0):

One of the dominant causes of death is atherosclerotic heart disease. Males are susceptible to this disease for their entire adult life with atheroma detectable as early as late teens and twenties. Females are moderately protected from developing this disease until menopause and the decline of estrogen, etc., after that point, they develop ASCVD as well. Therefore, if average duration f ASCVD is 20-30 years until death, men die in their 50-60's, women in their 70's-80's.